# Unable to convert JSON Array into a List in Java

Tags: java, json, list, jackson

I have an issue in converting JSONArray into a List using Jackson Object Mapper.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String test = Files.readString(Path.of("test.json"));
    callRequired(test);
}

public static void callRequired(String test) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        List<Condition> result = mapper.readerForListOf(Condition.class).readValue(test.trim());
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The test.json is:

```
{
    "condition": [
        {
            "type": "NONE",
            "subConditons": [
                {
                    "type": "NONE",
                    "subConditions": []
                },
                {
                    "type": "AND",
                    "subConditions": [
                        {
                            "type": "NONE",
                            "subConditions": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "OR",
            "subConditions": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The Condition class is as follows:

```
public class Condition {
Type type = Type.NONE;
List<Condition> subConditions;

public Condition() {
    
}

public Condition(Type type, List<Condition> subConditions) {
    this.type = type;
    this.subConditions = subConditions;
}

public List<Condition> getSubConditions() {
    return subConditions;
}

public void setSubConditions(List<Condition> subConditions) {
    this.subConditions = subConditions;
}

public Type getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public enum Type {
    NONE,
    AND,
    OR;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Condition [type=" + type + ", subConditions=" + subConditions + "]";
    }
}
```

**Edit**: The Condition array contains a list of conditions within which lies a subCondition which is also a type of Condition.

**EDIT:** Thanks, I have added the requisite braces and checked for its validity. I have also added an all args construcutor and a no args constructor as well.

**How do I change the JSON so that I receive a List of conditions with the proper subconditions nested with Jackson.**

Comment: Your json is not valid!

Comment: Specifically, your test string is missing `{` and `}`.  The rest of it looks good to my human eyes

Comment: And so, protip: don't put your string inside a string. Put it in a file, give that file a `.json` extension, and then load that file instead. Now you get the benefit of your IDE being able to properly flag errors in your JSON file. Also: if you're going to edit the code in your post, _run that updated code first_ to see if your problem even still exists with those edits.

Comment: I have updated the code with changes for my side. I have added constructors after running my code again and then updated the errors I have received.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON, the "condition" object starts with a "[", setting its type to an array. This isn't how your condition object class look like.

It should be more like:

```
[
    {
        "type" : "NONE",
        "subConditions" : []
    }
]
```

Comment: Exception says: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.simadvisory.Condition` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Comment: Yes, class Condition is not an array. Try it like I said.

Comment: You have misread my question. The Condition array contains a list of conditions within which lies a subCondition which is also a type of Condition. Check my Condition class.

Comment: I think the list of conditions called "condition" is as confusing to your parser as it is to me. However, your json denotes an object called condition, which contains an array of these condition objects, while your code seems to expect a list as the root object.

Comment: I still think you should not have the array inside the condition object, but start the file with "[".

Answer (score 0):

If you have no objection to switching to *[Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)*, here is a basic parse.

```java
String test = Files.readString(Path.of("test.json"));
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(test, JsonObject.class).get("condition");
List<Condition> conditions = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(element, Condition[].class));
```

```java
class Condition {
    Type type;
    List<Condition> subConditions;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(%s, %s)".formatted(type, subConditions);
    }
}

enum Type {
    NONE, AND, OR
}
```

Output

```
(NONE, [(NONE, []), (AND, [(NONE, [])])])
(OR, [])
```

Comment: That is a wonderful answer @Reilas. The output is exactly as I want! But my project needs Jackson.